# near-api-js signed contract deploy

Tags: nearprotocol

I am having trouble getting serverside near-api-js account creation and contract deployment working successfully and would appreciate some input.

I am using a unencrypted local keystore set up as follows;

```
const privatekey = "__private key__";
const keyPair = KeyPair.fromString(privatekey);  // generate key pair

const keyStore = new nearAPI.keyStores.UnencryptedFileSystemKeyStore(credentialsPath); // declare keystore type

const config = Object.assign(require('./config')('testnet'), {
networkId: networkId,
deps: { keyStore },
});  // setup config for near connection with keystore added

// update keystore with main account
await keyStore.setKey('testnet', config.masterAccount, nearAPI.utils.KeyPair.fromString(privatekey));

// connect near with config details
const near = await nearAPI.connect(config);

// load master account
const account = await new nearAPI.Account(near.connection, config.masterAccount);
```

I am creating a subaccount as;

```
const amountInYocto = utils.format.parseNearAmount("5");

// generate new public key
const newPublicKey = await near.connection.signer.createKey(newAccountName,config.networkId);

let keyPair;
let publicKey;

keyPair = await KeyPair.fromRandom('ed25519');
publicKey = keyPair.getPublicKey();

await near.connection.signer.keyStore.setKey(near.connection.networkId, newAccountName, keyPair);

const response = await near.createAccount(newAccountName, publicKey, amountInYocto);
```

When I try to deploy a contract to the created account I get the error;

Actor 'master account' doesn't have permission to account 'subaccount' to complete the action

This is how I deploy a contract:

```
const txs = [transactions.deployContract(fs.readFileSync(`../near/out/out.wasm`))];
const result = await account.signAndSendTransaction({
        receiverId: subaccount,
        actions: txs
    });
```

Im sure I have something wrong in how i manage the keys, but cannot work it out. Any suggestions?

Comment: I seem to have fixed the issue by changing near.connection.signer.keyStore.setKey, to keyStore.setKey (calling on original keystore not the one stored in near.connection).

Comment: You are allowed (and encouraged) to answer your own question.